# Efecto no deseado en background image en movil

Tags: html5, css3

Consulta, cuando abro mi portfolio en movil, se genera ese efecto que duplica el background, cuando scrolleo se corrije, en la version pc se ve bien y en la version mobile desde la pc tambien, alguien sabe a que se puede deber? Adjunto el screenshot[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, publica tu código para revisarlo

Comment: Revisando la Web que tienes en la imagen se ve bien `https://matiasaratano.github.io/`, no se muestra ese error

Comment: .home__background {
    background-image: url(img/codigo5.jpeg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: inherit;
    background-position: center;
  }
 
  .navbar{
    font-size: 0.8em;
  }
  
  .portfolio__img {
    object-fit: contain;
  }

  .home__description {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }

Comment: me sucede solamente cuando lo veo desde el movil,

Comment: Lo revisé en la PC tanto en Firefox como Chrome, cambién el tamaño del navegador hasta la versión móvil y tambien lo abrí directamente desde mi móvil. Se vió bien siempre.

Comment: Muchas gracias Joseph!, es extraño porque solo me sucede a veces desde mi iphone, desde la web no me paso nunca.

Comment: Intenta agregando no-repeat al css `.home__background { 
 background-image: url(img/codigo5.jpeg); background-attachment: fixed; 
 background-size: inherit; 
 background-position: center; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}`

Comment: Quizás se presenta solo en el navegador del Iphone, los diseños a veces no se muestran igual en todos los navegadores

Comment: probe con safari y google chrome desde el movil y pasa lo mismo, probe el background-repeat y me desaparecio el background jaja, probe cambiando las propiedades pero me sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: Habría que revisar el soporte de `background-repeat: no-repeat;` en los navegadores y versiones, por no dejar intenta con `background-repeat: no-repeat !important;`

Comment: Por favor, agrega un [example]. Revisa [ask]